# c++ GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents fail = communication with another process

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt, winapi

I run external app on windows using `QProcess` class.
And this external app instantly crashes after this.
This external app crash on code like this:

```
    HANDLE sh = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (sh == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      abort();
    DWORD eventsNum;
    if (!GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(sh, &eventsNum))
        abort();
```

`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` fails and `GetLastError` return 6 = invalid handle. So looks like `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` not works with pipes?
Is it possible to work with console handle in uniform way, so I can receive number of available bytes in stdin without knowledge that this is pipe/console?

In other words I want my app works in both cases: when I run it from `cmd.exe` and when I run it from another app, which uses pipes (or what else use `QProcess` to redirect child stdin).

I could not use `FILE *stdin` because of I need `WaitFor...` function to work with stdin.

Comment: You can make it uniform by initializing *eventsNum* to 42 and not calling abort() when the function fails.  Passing the handle to WaitFor...() is fine.

Comment: @HansPassant in that case it stops working as expected at all, because of I used such construction to not block on stdin.

Comment: So you wrote a program that will also fail when ran by a user that types really fast.  Not much of feature, is it?  Fix it.

Comment: @HansPassant why it fails if user type too fast?

Comment: Because then GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents() will never return 0 events, just like the alternative I proposed.

Comment: @HansPassant current variant with console not blocks, because of `waitformultipleobjects` -> `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` -> `reading not more than data exists`, you suggest replace `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` with 42, obviously after that code blocks on `reading not more than data exists` if we have < 42 input characters.

Comment: That is all quite obvious, what is not obvious is why you have not tried it yet and what *actually* went wrong when you did.  Bye.

Comment: `QProcess` is broken beyond hope of regeneration. Use something more sane if you are looking for robust IPC.

Comment: @IInspectable Why do you think that `QProcess` broken? The same problem happens if I just run `echo hi | external_app`.

Comment: The fact that *external_app* is broken doesn't fix `QProcess`. The way `QProcess` tries to redirect standard streams is written by someone that never consulted the documentation. It works, by accident, if at all.